# How do I find out the row delimiter of a file?

Tags: node.js, csv, parsing

I have a csv file and I am trying to parse each row, however I only get back one line. I have a feeling it is because the row delimeter is not '\n'.

Is there a way to find out what it is?

I am using fast-csv on nodeJS

Comment: Look at it with a text editor?

Comment: if a text editor won't show the character, use a hex editor

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I tried that, it doesn't say what it is. Just shows new lines

Comment: If a text editor shows it properly broken into lines and you know it's not \n then it's probably \r.

Comment: Commonly there are \r\n together, so it could be one or the other or both. A hex editor will show what is actually there. (CRLF) 0x0a and 0x0d are the newline and carriage return in ASCII
http://www.bluesock.org/~willg/dev/ascii.html

Comment: @DanielGale I tried a hex editor and saw 0D 0A which i believe to be \r\n

Comment: That is correct. So when you are parsing for newline, look for \r\n together. I have seen it in some places as {CRLF}. Not sure what you have for code.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thank you for the help, I used a hex editor and found the hex equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DanielGale and @500-InternalServerError both helped me to arrive at the answer.

What I did was on Mac:

1) Opened file with Xcode

2) CMD+SHIFT+J

3) right click file name, and click Open As Hex

You should now see the hex representation and the Text representation.

4) Highlight the space at the end of the line and you will see it highlight the Hex representation.

0D means \r and 0A means \n

Thanks Daniel and 500 internal Server for helping me find this.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at it with a text editor, like **Notepad++**. There you will get a menu button named "Show All Characters", You will have to enable it.